# Missing ")" en JS

Tags: javascript, html

En la consola del navegador me da el siguiente fallo al darle al botón. La función que accede al darle click se encarga de no permitir que una ventana creada se re dimensione. Alguien podría decirme cual es error de sintaxis?

```js
function createWindow(src, width, height){
    var win = window.open(src, "_new", "width="+width+,"height="+height);
    win.addEventListener("resize", function(){
        console.log("Resized");
  win.resizeTo(width, height);
    });
}
```

```html
<button onclick="createWindow('about:blank', 450, 250)">Crear ventana</button>
```

Comment: El parámetro SRC debe ser un string `'about:blank'`

Comment: He actualizado la pregunta ya que sigue dandoime fallos, alguna idea ?

Comment: Coloca la comilla como estaba, no había visto bien que ya la habías colocado

Comment: tengo una idea puedes colocar una imagen del error que da la consola y en su defecto colocar tambien los detalles del error???

Comment: Ya esta solucionado, el problema que me daba era que faltaba una parentesis. pero el problema era que en la funcion la tenia mal escrita, y que a la hora de hacer la sobrecarga de la funcion en la llamada el parametro about:blank lo puse sin coimillas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El parámetro SRC de la función `window.open()` debe ser un string: `'about:blank'`

http://jsfiddle.net/2pb1L4u5/

Te dejo la solución en jsfiddle porque aquí los snippets no tienen permiso de abrir ventanas

Comment: Gracias me ayudaste ;D. Ahora doy voto positivo

Comment: @Eduardo si la respuesta fue la solución te invito a marcarla como aceptada para que los futuros desarrolladores que tengan el mismo problema sepan que fue la solución correcta, recuerda leer [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) saludos !

Comment: Claro eso iba a hacer. Pero debido a la politica de StackOverFlow me impide darle a una respuesta aceptada pasada unos minutos. en cuantopueda lo hare con mucho gusto. Gracias por la informacion .

Comment: @CamiloVasquez la solución a la pregunta **es un  error tipográfico**.